# $localStorage gives value in one state and is undefined in another state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, local-storage

I'm defining two states **finance.payment** and **finance.ppm** where **finance** is already a state

This is the payment.js file

```js
angular.module('erpSaarangFrontendApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('finance.payment', {
        url: '/payments',
        templateUrl: 'views/finance/payment.html',
        controller: 'FinancePaymentCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      });
  })
  .controller('FinancePaymentCtrl',['$scope', '$http','Upload','cloudinary', '$localStorage', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $upload, cloudinary, $localStorage, $state) {

      var config = {
                  headers:{
                    'Authorization' : "Bearer "+ $localStorage.auth_token,
                }
             };

             console.log($localStorage.auth_token);
             }]);
```

The console output for payment.js is

```js
y1kw3j9lhb7rj4ld8rzwkhe0a9xymwlv
```

This is ppm.js file

```js
angular.module('erpSaarangFrontendApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('finance.ppm', {
        url: '/prizemoney',
        templateUrl: 'views/finance/ppm.html',
        controller: 'FinancePpmCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      });
  })
  .controller('FinancePpmCtrl',['$scope','$http','Upload','cloudinary','$location','$localStorage','$state', function ($scope, $http, $upload, cloudinary, $localStorage, $state) {
  
          var config = {
                  headers:{
                    'Authorization' : "Bearer "+ $localStorage.auth_token,
                }
             };

             console.log($localStorage.auth_token);
}]);
```

The console output for ppm.js is

```js
undefined
```

When i print the $localStorage for payment.js , i get this -

```js
Object { $default: $default(), $reset: $reset(), $sync: $sync(), $apply: $apply(), $supported: $supported(), auth_token: "y1kw3j9lhb7rj4ld8rzwkhe0a9xymwlv", member: Object, _id: 8190 }
```

But when i print the $localStorage for ppm.js , i get this -

```js
Object { $$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 9000, $$parse: LocationHashbangUrl/this.$$parse(), $$compose: LocationHashbangUrl/this.$$compose(), $$parseLinkUrl: LocationHashbangUrl/this.$$parseLinkUrl(), $$path: "/finance/prizemoney", $$search: Object, $$hash: "", $$url: "/finance/prizemoney", 4 more… }
```

I don't understand, how $localStorage is varying ? and also why auth_token is undefined in ppm.js whereas it has a value in payment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@robin: In ppm.js file, you injected `$localStorage` at `6 position` but, in function it is on `5th position`.

Position of injection and passing inside the function should be same.

So, actually `$localStorage` is getting parameter in function is actually getting passed as `$location`

Comment: Ah! Thanks mate...i don't know how i missed such a minute error

Comment: @Robin: My pleasure to help u! You can also accept this answer if it really helped u :)